# Inserting base64 encoded dataURI image into MySQL BLOB field

Tags: php, mysql, base64, blob

I am trying to insert a base64 encoded dataURI image (sent via Ajax:post) into a BLOB field of a MySQL table with success. Currently the field is being populated, but when I display the image, it is corrupt.

Data is being sent via Ajax with no problems.

Here is my PHP code (simplified):

```
$encodedData = filter_var($_POST['encodedData'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$encodedData = str_replace(' ','+',$encodedData);
$encodedData = substr($encodedData, strpos($encodedData, ",") + 1);
$decodedData = base64_decode($encodedData);
$doinsertphoto = mysql_query("INSERT INTO subscriber_photo (SubscriberId, Photo) VALUES ('" . $subscriber_id . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($decodedData) . "')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Found the reason why it was not working. The imagecreatefromstring() function was not needed and all I had to do was to add a mysql_real_escape_string() to the database query. Updating the code above.

Answer (score 0):

If you read PHP manual for base64_encode at http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php, you can see this function return string type date, and MySQL Blob data type field is use to store binary data, So you are trying to save String (ASCII) code into binary data, this is the problem.

Either you save image binary content into blob type without  encoding or use varchar or text type to save encoded data.

Comment: This is why I am using imagecreatefromstring() function?

Comment: @GuvencKaplan, can you please elaborate this?

Comment: What you want me to elaborate? imagecreatefromstring() should create a binary from a string.